# Do I need to create <ALT Tags> for Images created by react-leaflet (OpenStreetMap)?

Tags: react-leaflet

I need some advice on a problem I noticed with the implementation of OSM using react-leaflet. As there are images created, some SEO tools flag these map-images as a (SEO) problem due to the missing alt-tag.

There is nothing the documentation mentioned about such. So the question is, do I add such tags or what else should I do about it? This is not only for SEO, it also increases accessibility to better understand images - the map in this case.

Thanks for helping me out here.

Answer (score 0):

A workaround would be to listen to the tileload event, which gets triggered each time a tile is loaded onto the map. You can then add the alt attribute to each tile after it has been loaded. Here's an example using :

```
var map = L.map('map').setView([51.505, -0.09], 13);

L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', { 
    attribution: '© OpenStreetMap contributors'
}).on('tileload', function(e) {
    e.tile.alt = 'Image description';
}).addTo(map);
```

Note that this is intentional. You can find this piece of information in Leaflet's source code in createTile: function

```
// The alt attribute is set to the empty string,
// allowing screen readers to ignore the decorative image tiles.
// https://www.w3.org/WAI/tutorials/images/decorative/
// https://www.w3.org/TR/html-aria/#el-img-empty-alt
tile.alt = '';
```